# Change data source on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and I am trying to make a chart where people could change the data  source on click. To give a concrete example, if I display a country's population over time, I'd like to have a button for each country and when people click on it, it updates the source.

My initial chart is defined here:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("./javascripts/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

And when people click on a button, I'd like to change the source:

```
function updateData() {
  // Get the data again
  d3.tsv("./javascripts/data2.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);

    // Scale the range of the data again
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").transition();
    // Make the changes
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data) // here I get: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
      .exit().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

  });
}
```

However this is not working. I get the error commented in the code.

What I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: This means that the data isn't loaded correctly. Verify that it is where you think it is and examine `error`.

Comment: however the data is logged correctly on the console and error is 'null'

Comment: Oh wait, you're defining `svg` to be a transition. This won't work -- define it to be a selection.